# Не работает геймпад xbox series через USB Manjaro

Tags: linux, драйвер, manjaro

Установил xone-dkms 0.3-3 через AUR, но всё равно ничего. В системе нет, в стиме нет, а при подключении вибрация и мигает кнопка когда нажимаю.